# How compactness differes if we change the topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $E=(L^{2}(\mathbb R), \|\cdot \|_{L^2})$ is a Banach space (where $\|f\|_{L^2}^{2}= \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2 dx$) We note that $(L^{2}(\mathbb R), \|\cdot \|_{L^2})$ automatically generates a topology, known as the norm topology or strong topology on $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$, generated by the open balls

$B(x, r)= \{y: \|x-y\|_{L^2}<r \}.$  A sequence ${x_n}$ in such a space converges strongly (or converges in norm) to a limit ${x}$ if and only if y if ${\|x_n-x\|_{L^{2}} \rightarrow 0}$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}. $

Next, we consider the [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) on $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$: A subset of $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ is open in the weak topology if and only if it can be written as a union of (possibly infinitely many) sets, each of which is an intersection of finitely many sets of the form $\phi^{-1}(U)$ where $\phi \in (L^{2})^{*} = \{\phi : L^{2}(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R: \phi \  \text{linear} \}.$

> My Questions; (1) Can we find a  set $K\subset L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ such that $K$ is compact in $L^{2}$ with respect to strong topology but not with respect to weak topology? (2) Can we find a  set $K\subset L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ such that $K$ is compact in $L^{2}$ with respect to weak topology but not with respect to strong topology?  (3) Can you give some examples of compact and noncompact sets in $L^{2}$ with respect both strong and weak topology? (4) Let $X$ be a topological space with two topology $T_1$
>    and $T_2$ such that $T_1 \subset T_2.$ Let $K\subset X.$ If $X$ is compact in $(X, T_1)$, then can we say  $X$ is compact in $(X, T_2)$? What about the converse?

Comment: Relevant example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem

Comment: Think of compactness as the possibility of selecting a finite subcover from any cover with open sets. What happens if you have a topology with less/more open sets?